# How to target custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a plugin that creates custom taxonomy categories for showing portfolio. On hovering Edit categories on admin panel, i see link like :

> localhost/site/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=mg_item_categories&tag_id=13&post_type=mg_items

What i want to do is add some CSS (a ribbon image), if product displays from a specific category. For example if products from category 'new' are displayed, it all shows "New Ribbon Image" So i am confused how can i target taxonomy? Any idea from the above link?

Should i use `is_post_type`, `is_taxonomy` or anything else that can help targetting taxonomy ID 13.

Here is the function that makes this taxonomy :

```
function register_cpt_mg_item() {
$labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Item Categories', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Item Category', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Item Categories', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'popular_items' => NULL,
        'all_items' => _x( 'All Item Categories', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent Item Category', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Item Category:', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Item Category', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update Item Category', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Item Category', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New Item Category', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate item categories with commas', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove Item Categories', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from most used Item Categories', 'mg_item_categories' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Item Categories', 'mg_item_categories' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'mg_item_categories', array('mg_items'), $args );
}
```

Comment: check for css-classes in your themes output that are specific to that category. E.g. search by the numeric ID of that category. You probably directly find something so you can solve this in your CSS easily.

Answer (score 0):

**`using this code get your '13' category taxonomy post :`**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'mg_item_categories',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => '13'
            )),

'post_type'=>'mg_items',
'order'=>'ASC',
'posts_per_page'=>-1
);

query_posts($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full');   
?>
    <h2> <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php   
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: How can i target using this code? How can i use if() in the above code. something like if(terms =13) thankyou

Comment: if(term=13) not require for this code beacuase of using this code only term=13 post display.